# If $a=b^c$, $b=c^a$, and $c=a^b$, prove that

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $$a=b^c, \quad b=c^a, \quad \text{and} \quad c=a^b$$ prove that $$abc=1.$$

My Attempt;

Given,
$$a=b^c$$
$$b=c^a$$
$$c=a^b$$

Now,

$$
\begin{align}
\text{L.H.S.} & =abc \\
& = b^c\cdot b\cdot a^b \\
& =b^c\cdot b\cdot b^{bc} \\
& =b^{c+1+bc} \\
& \,\,\,\vdots
\end{align}
$$

I got struck from here.

Please help to complete.

Comment: $b^{cba}=a^{ba}=c^a=b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$abc = a^bb^cc^a$$
$$\implies \log(abc) = \log(a^bb^cc^a)$$
$$\implies \log(abc) = \log b^c + \log c^a + \log a^b$$
$$\implies \log(abc) = c\log b + a\log c + b\log a$$
$$\implies \log(abc) = c\log c^a + a\log a^b + b\log b^c$$
$$\implies \log(abc) = ac\log c + ab\log a + bc\log b$$
$$\implies \log(abc) = ac\log a^b + ab\log b^c + bc\log c^a$$
$$\implies \log(abc) = abc\log a + abc\log b + abc\log c$$
$$\implies \log(abc) = abc(\log a + \log b + \log c)$$
$$\implies \log(abc) = abc\log(abc)$$
$$\implies 1 = abc$$

Not the shortest proof, but I consider it by far the most beautiful I could think of due to the symmetry in the logarithm steps!

Comment: How do you know $a>0$? $a=b=c=-1$ works

Comment: @ZacharySelk you are absolutely right, and I saw the post by SimpleArt prior to answering. The OP asks for a proof that it equals 1, implying that $abc = 1$ *must* be true. I implicitly assume this means that $a,b,c > 0$, though you are correct - The OP never says so explicitly. However, if I don't accept that each variable is non-negative then the OP's conclusion cannot be reached!

Answer (score 6):

In $a=b^c$, substitute $b=c^a$, and you get $a=(c^a)^c=c^{ac}$. Next substitute $c=a^b$ and get $a=(a^b)^{ac}=a^{abc}$. So $a^{1}=a^{abc}$. Either $abc=1$ or $a=1$.

If $a=1$ then $c=a^b=1$ and $b=c^a=1$, so $abc=1$ again.

Comment: How do you know $a>0$? $a=b=c=-1$ works

Comment: @ZacharySelk He didn't know.  He said "If", which it indeed works.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer that involves logarithms.

if $a=b^c$, $b=c^a$, $c=a^b$ then we may write that

$c=\log_{b}(a)$,$a=\log_{c}(b)$ and $b=\log_{a}(c)$

Hence we have that $abc=\log_{b}(a)\log_{c}(b)\log_{a}(c)$. Then by using change of base rule we get

$abc=\frac{\log_{e}(a)}{\log_{e}(b)}\frac{\log_{e}(b)}{\log_{e}(c)}\frac{\log_{e}(c)}{\log_{e}(a)}$

Notice that all the logarithms on the right hand side cancel out and we get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

$$
a^1 = a = b^c = (c^a)^c = c^{ac} = (a^b)^{ac} = a^{bac},
$$
so
$$
a^1 = a^{bca}.
$$
Now take base-$a$ logarithms of both sides.

Comment: How do you know $a$ is positive? Couldn't $a=b=c=-1$ work?

Comment: @ZacharySelk You don't actually know, the solution $a=b=c=-1$ is simply due to the way you take the log of both sides, which has problems when we allow multiple branches of the log.

Comment: @ZacharySelk : Generally I assume a number raised to a real power (which may not be an integer power) is nonnegative.  Raising a negative number to a non-integer power can be problematic. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I note that $a=b=c=-1$ works just as well, which contradicts everyone's statements that $abc=1$.

Comment: You are absolutely right, and I saw your post prior to answering. The OP asks for a proof that it equals 1, implying that $abc = 1$ *must* be true. I implicitly assume this means that $a,b,c > 0$, though you are correct - The OP never says so explicitly. However, if I don't accept that each variable is non-negative then the OP's conclusion cannot be reached, so I did so anyway! Your observation **is** critical though - the OP must add some criterion on the domain of $a$, $b$, and $c$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Yeah, I saw your answer as well, and it most certainly was neat and well made.  I just happened upon this answer by chance. ;D Noting that $|a|=|b|=|c|=1$, but with the restriction of the solutions being positive, of course, everyone else is just as right.  :)